# Does this table need a new primary key?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

The part of an ERD shows the relation between 3 tables.

A user can own many tarcks (songs)

A track can be owned by many users

the table in the middle resolves the many to many relationship and has a composite primary key. As well as storing information on how specific users rate specific tracks.

[image]

Does the middle table need a new primary key "User_Rating_ID" or is it okay (better?) to leave it as a composite key?

Answer (score 1):

The intersection table defines a relationship between two entities. If that is an anonymous relationship, then a separate surrogate key is not needed.

For example, a table of Parts and a table of Units can have a table which defines which parts are used to make each Unit. Each part can be used in several units and each unit is made up of many parts (and sometimes several of a particular part). Such a table may look like this:

```
UnitID  PartID  Qty
```

Such an intersection table would likely not have a surrogate key. Common questions being asked of the relationship will be:

- Which parts are used to make Unit X?
- What is the cheapest/most expensive part used to make Unit X?
- Which units contain part P?
- Which units require the highest number of part P?

I can't think of any circumstance where a separate key of this relationship would even be used. All questions will concern a particular part or a particular unit.

On the other hand, take a course and semester. The intersection table would establish the classes, the specific session where a course would be taught. Here there may be several instances of a particular course within the same semester. There could be a Math-101 class for 1 hour each day on m-w-f by Prof. Smith and for 1.5 hours each day on t-th by Prof. Jones.

During registration and other future record keeping, it will *not* be Math-101 or the semester that will be tracked but the *particular* class that will be used. For this reason, a separate surrogate key would be needed.

Analysis will determine in your instance whether the relationship is anonymous or not.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using the data.

From a strictly logical point of view, the composite primary key says what needs to be said, and works justt fine.  There are a few unusual situations where having a separate PK can be helpful.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on these situations or pointing me in the right direction? I googled around the issue but could not find anything particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with a many-to-many intersection table having a composite primary key made up of the two foreign key columns which point at the two tables being linked via the intersection.

Some people might like to add an additional candidate primary key, particularly a meaningless, system generated ID number (or GUID, etc.) to such intersection tables as well.

The reasons that someone may do this would include:*

1. The "parent" (linked) tables may change at one end and updating one (or more) of the foreign keys would be complicated for some reason.  Some people don't like updating primary keys.  Some ORMs don't allow it.
2. The intersection may itself be a parent for one or more child tables which need to have a foreign key that points to the intersection.  Propagating compound keys to other tables can complicate your code and may or may not be supported by your ORM, if you're using one.
3. Sometimes you have a user interface-based reason for having a single column candidate key, like the records in your intersection are being displayed in a combo box and the combo box control has a single list item integer array that lets you identify the record from the intersection table.
4. You may have some kind of system constraint that requires you to have a single surrogate key on each one of your tables, regardless of what other candidate primary keys are present.  For example, you might have an audit logging mechanism that tracks items like `table_name`, `record_id`, `change_date`, `change_user`, and so forth.
5. Some people just feel like every table needs to have a surrogate key, because that is their world view.

*** NOTE:** I'm not advocating for any of these reasons.  I'm stating that they are opinions that you'll find "out in the wild".  Your mileage may vary, make your own decisions, etc.